# IssuableSubscriptionVisitor & BaseTreeVisitor

Tags: java, sonarqube

I would like to ask when writing custom rules for java in SonarQube, in which circumstances does the test logic class extends IssuableSubscriptionVisitor and which circumstances is BaseTreeVisitor extended instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That depends what you are trying to achieve. Ususally the subscription visitor is a bit simpler to implement but the visit of the AST is handled for you and you can't control it which the BaseTreeVisitor allows you to do which can be required when implementing rules with a bit of complexity.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

So no matter which class is extended, the outcome is the same?

Would you have any examples on each scenario?

Thank you.

Comment: You can have a look at how SonarJava checks are implemented : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/tree/master/java-checks